# ajax autocomplete same data with multiple textbox jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, autocomplete

i have one issue with jquery autocomplete, its working with one textbox perfect but when i create multiple textbox using jquery with same ID at that time its working for only first textbox not for another textbox .
my question is i want to create multiple textbox and implement same autocomplete data with all text box

this is my code for create textbox using jquery

```
var totalSelect = $('#max_player').val();
    $('#competitor_box').empty();
    for (var i = 1; i <= totalSelect; i++) {
        var ajaxauto = '<div class="form-group col-sm-3"><label for="tournament_name">Pocker # '+i+'</label><input id="autocomplete-ajax" type="text" class="form-control" autocomplete="off"></div>';
        $('#competitor_box').append(ajaxauto);
    }
```

this code for ajax autocomplete

```
$('#autocomplete-ajax').autocomplete({
    // serviceUrl: '/autosuggest/service/url',
    lookup: countriesArray,
    lookupFilter: function(suggestion, originalQuery, queryLowerCase) {
        var re = new RegExp('\\b' + $.Autocomplete.utils.escapeRegExChars(queryLowerCase), 'gi');
        return re.test(suggestion.value);
    },
    onSelect: function(suggestion) {
        $('#selction-ajax').html('You selected: ' + suggestion.value + ', ' + suggestion.data);
    },
    onHint: function (hint) {
        $('#autocomplete-ajax-x').val(hint);
    },
    onInvalidateSelection: function() {
        $('#selction-ajax').html('You selected: none');
    }
});
```

please help me for this issue its very important for me 
thanks all.

Comment: _"...create multiple textbox using jquery with same ID..."_ . `ID` should be unique in whole document. You probably want to use classes.

Answer (score 1):

```
    var totalSelect = $('#max_player').val();
        $('#competitor_box').empty();
        for (var i = 1; i <= totalSelect; i++) {
            var ajaxauto = '<div class="form-group col-sm-3"><label for="tournament_name">Pocker # '+i+'</label><input class="txtAutocomplete" type="text" class="form-control" autocomplete="off"></div>';
            $('#competitor_box').append(ajaxauto);   
        }
```

Autocomplete function

```
    $('.txtAutocomplete').autocomplete({
        // serviceUrl: '/autosuggest/service/url',
        lookup: countriesArray,
        lookupFilter: function(suggestion, originalQuery, queryLowerCase) {
            var re = new RegExp('\\b' + $.Autocomplete.utils.escapeRegExChars(queryLowerCase), 'gi');
            return re.test(suggestion.value);
        },
        onSelect: function(suggestion) {
            $('#selction-ajax').html('You selected: ' + suggestion.value + ', ' + suggestion.data);
        },
        onHint: function (hint) {
            $('#autocomplete-ajax-x').val(hint);
        },
        onInvalidateSelection: function() {
            $('#selction-ajax').html('You selected: none');
        }
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

why did you use the same ID for severals input ? use classes if you have to tag multiples elements, for example `.autocomplete-ajax-input` on each textbox. And then declare your autocomple function with `$('.autocomplete-ajax-input').autocomplete`